# Android NDK: Why arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe disappeared?

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, qt-creator

I recently migrated from Android NDK r9b to r11b.

I'm deploying test application using QtCreator, this uses the NDK for compilation.

I'm not able to debug anymore, QtCreator complains that it cannot find `arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe`.

And I confirm:

- **r9b** has file toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.8\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe
- **r11b** does not have it in toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
- I downloaded and checked **r10e**, this one also contains toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe

Why did they remove GDB from release r11b? How are we supposed to debug now?

**Edit:** Submitted Qt bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-15933. gdb can be manually picked up somewhere else in NDK folder. However, I was still unable to debug after gdb.exe was found...

**Edit2:** Problem fixed by Qt. Upgraded to QtCreator 4.0.3. It piskcs up gdb correctly and I could debug my application!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In NDK 11 gdb was moved to $NDK_DIR/prebuilt/$HOST/bin/gdb.

QtCreator was updated for NDK 11. E.g. you can try QtCreator 4.0 beta

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try that. What's the easiest way to get QtCreator 4.0 beta binaries installer for Windows?

Comment: Got it and just tested. It does pickup gdb.exe in the right place....but it does not stop on breakpoints, and when I pause it is unable to show me any stack...

Comment: Hmm, on Linux I don't see this problem.

Comment: check settings http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-qml.html#mixed-c-qml-debugging

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86_64.exe
This package has an bug which skips copying arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe to the destination folder.
Here is my workaround ... Since downloaded android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86_64.exe contains missing arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe ...

- Open 7-zip and extract *android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86_64.exe* to local
  folder
- Open extracted folder and
- Browse to
  android-ndk-r10e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\
- Copy arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe to your NDK location

Hope this helps.
[View  listof files in 7-zip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzuO0.png)